# Bash filepath on Windows 10 is incorrect

Tags: command-line, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to setup a dev environment on Windows 10. I installed Ubuntu and I'm using Hyper as my CLI. My main objective is to get my CLI to point to my development directory by default when I open the window, which is `C:/Users/linds/Development`

**.hyper.js Setting**

```
shell: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\bash.exe',
shellArgs: ['~', '--login'],
```

The default shellArgs in Hyper were:

```
shellArgs: ['--login'],
```

**.profile**

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
        . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

**.bash_profile**

```
cd ~/C:/Users/linds/Development
```

**.bashrc**

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes
```

When I startup my Terminal, I get the following message:

```
bash: cd: /home/scribbles/C:/Users/linds/Development: No such file or directory
scribbles@DESKTOP-IQ51GOV:~$
```

I am not sure where the `/home/scribbles/` is coming from, but I think it might have something to do with .profile - I'm not entirely sure though.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: To clarify, scribbles is my Ubuntu username.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out that bash stores files differently. To change the default file path, instead of trying `cd ~/C:/Users/linds/Development` I instead had to change my `.bash_profile` to `cd /mnt/c/Users/linds/Development` - this opens my CLI in the correct directory every time.

Tested it with `mkdir test` and it worked perfectly! =) Hope this helps someone else out!